# How do I spawn parallel threads on different devices?

Tags: opencl, removable-storage

I want to run some threads on my CPU ( the `localhost` host ) and some other on a portable device connected ( like a USB ).

I know that OpenCL supports parallelization, but how do I distribute a work onto a portable devices using OpenCL?

Any other idea to do this other than OpenCL would also help.

Comment: What do you mean by "portable device"? What kind of device is this? Does it have an OpenCL implementation?

Comment: You would enumerate all OpenCL platforms in the system, and all devices in each platform, and then you would compile your kernel (possibly different versions of it) for the devices that you want to use, and then queue the work on those devices. Your program will need to explicitly implement the logic for distributing the workload across all the devices that it uses.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any device which might run an OpenCL task must have an Installable Client Driver associated with it, which can be picked up by the OpenCL Driver on the computer in question. Graphics Cards (especially if they're no older than half a decade) are nearly guaranteed to have a valid ICD, provided their drivers are up-to-date, and many Consumer-level CPUs have ICDs that are provided by their drivers.

However, other devices like a Network Device or a USB device are considerably less guaranteed to have a valid ICD unless they've been specifically designed for use in a Heterogeneous Compute system. **If they do have a valid ICD**, then it's a mere matter of querying for their platform at runtime and choosing it to use when constructing your OpenCL Context, then using it the same way you'd use OpenCL normally:

```
//C++ OpenCL API
cl::Platform target_platform;
std::vector<cl::Platform> platforms;
cl::Platform::get(&platforms);
for(cl::Platform & platform : platforms) {
    std::string name = platform.getInfo<CL_PLATFORM_NAME>();
    if(name == /*Whatever the Name of the platform is*/) {
        target_platform = platform;
        break;
    }
}
std::vector<cl::Device> devices;
target_platform.getDevices(CL_DEVICE_TYPE_ALL, &devices);
cl::Device target_device;
for(cl::Device & device : devices) {
    if(device.getInfo</*...*/>() == /*...*/) {//Whatever properties you need
        target_device = device;
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: What if they do not have a valid ICD ? How do I create a valid ICD for that device in that case ?

Comment: @Jatin That's something the device's manufacturer would create. Unless you want to spend a few thousand hours studying the device's data sheets and working out how to build a driver for it. ;) Bear in mind that the drivers you're using might not be up-to-date: make sure you're using the latest versions.